# Java Hibernate 4.3 subquery SUM inside select

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this situation in **Hibernate 4.3.x**.

1. I have 2 tables, product and inventory
2. I have a 1 to many relationship, 1 product has many inventories
3. The availability of a product is checked by making a sum of inventories available in the table of inventory.

So I have this custom query:

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    p.status_id, 
    p.product_name, 
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(i.available),0) FROM inventory i WHERE i.product_id = p.product_id AND i.status_id = 1) AS available 
FROM product p
```

I want to make this query using criteria, I am stuck making the sum subquery inside select, how do I do this in Hibernate? Do I have to use projections? How do I use projections in this case?

Comment: what is the where clause? if it is always the same and only the parameter values change.. then maybe you should go for a @NamedQuery which is always preferred approach. Then you would be using JPQL instead of criteria.

Comment: Hi @MaciejKowalski, I didn't put the WHERE clause because I don't need it at the moment, I want to list all the products. Did you mean HQL?

Comment: In that case i would go for JPQL / HQL (depending whether you use SessionFactory or EntityManagerFactory). Crtieria should be only used when the structure of the query could change based on some logic. Here it is not the case. Did you try with HQL already.. and if yes did you have problems?